# How do I speed up searching through files on a network drive and prevent "not responding" in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, performance

Part of my application searches for a string provided by a textbox within .txt files and .pdf files stored on a network drive. It works great on my PC when looking within a directory of a few files stored on a local disk, when I run it on my work PC which is less beefy and looking at a network drive I get "not responding" and it takes a good few minutes to finally wake up again. This is only searching through around 100 files and that number is only going to get bigger.

I thought about adding a progress bar, but if the application is not responding I assume the progress bar will not update? I would be very grateful to hear the advice of someone much more experienced in this than me.

In short, the code searches as described above, uses the name of the folder (that begins with SCC) to add an item to a listbox. If it cannot search the PDF for any reason then it adds it to another listbox displaying the folder names it was unable to search.

Here is the section of code that does the search:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim path As String = ""
    Dim list As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)
    Dim raf As itextsharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray = Nothing
    Dim reader As itextsharp.text.pdf.PdfReader = Nothing
    Dim searchPhrase As String = faultSearch.Text

    VINListBox.Items.Clear()
```

## Region "search plain text"

```
    'finds text within faultSearch textbox within the files in directory
    list = My.Computer.FileSystem.FindInFiles(archive_dir, faultSearch.Text, True, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories)

    For Each foundFile As String In list
        path = foundFile
        GetVinName(path)
    Next
```

## End Region

## Region "search PDF"

```
    'Finds text within faultSearch textbox within PDF files in directory
    For Each file As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(archive_dir, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories)
        If System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file).ToUpper = ".PDF" Then

            Try
                raf = New itextsharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray(file)
                reader = New itextsharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(raf, Nothing)
                For i As Integer = 1 To reader.NumberOfPages()
                    Dim pageText As String = itextsharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i)
                    If pageText.ToUpper.Contains(searchPhrase) Then
                        GetVinName(file)
                    End If
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
                GetErrVinName(file)
            End Try

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

## End Region

```
Private Sub GetVinName(ByVal strVIN As String)
    Dim fldName() As String

    fldName = Split(strVIN.ToString, "\",, CompareMethod.Text)

    For x = 0 To UBound(fldName) - 1
        If InStr(fldName(x), "SCC", CompareMethod.Text) > 0 Then

            strVIN = Trim(fldName(x))
            If errListBox.Items.Contains(strVIN) = True Then
                errListBox.Items.Remove(strVIN)
            End If
            If VINListBox.Items.Contains(strVIN) = False Then
                VINListBox.Items.Add(strVIN)
            End If
            Exit For
            End If
    Next

End Sub


Private Sub GetErrVinName(ByVal strVIN As String)
    Dim fldName() As String
    fldName = Split(strVIN.ToString, "\",, CompareMethod.Text)

    For x = 0 To UBound(fldName) - 1
        If InStr(fldName(x), "SCC", CompareMethod.Text) > 0 Then
            strVIN = Trim(fldName(x))

            If VINListBox.Items.Contains(strVIN) = False Then
                If errListBox.Items.Contains(strVIN) = False Then
                    errListBox.Items.Add(strVIN)
                Else
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) can be used to make it responsive. I don't think it can be much faster if it can't be run on the server that has the files, as it is dependent mostly on the network speed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will look into BackgroundWorker, it's not something I've used before!